# modulo of a number - python vs c#

Tags: c#, python

Lets take the basic arithmetic operation - **modulo**

I get different outputs depending on different languages.

**Python**

```
>>> -1 % 12
11
```

**C#**

```
var res = -1 % 12;
output: res = -1
```

Why am I seeing such behaviour? Ideally I'd like the output to be **11** in both cases.

Also does anyone know if I can achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The premise of the question is incorrect.  The `%` operator in C# is not the modulus operator, it is the *remainder* operator, while in Python it *is* a modulus operator.

As [Eric Lippert Describes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx), modulus and remainder are the same for all positive numbers, but they handle negative numbers differently.

Despite both C# and Python having a `%` operator, doesn't mean they both represent a modulus.

It's worth noting that other languages, such as C++ and Java use remainder for the `%` operator, not modulus, which likely contributed to why C# choose to use remainder as well.  Since there isn't a lot of consistency in what is meant by the `%` operator, I would suggest looking it up in the language docs whenever working with a new language.

Comment: Thanks @Servy for the comprehensive answer. I'll definitely be aware of this next time I am working with a new language. Thanks

Comment: @RoadieRich: Yeah, I meant to nuke that comment.

Comment: I've always found the way a modulus operator works much, MUCH more useful than what's called a "remainder" operator here. Whether I'm dealing with positioning evenly-spaced images in a coordinate space that has negative values, or dealing with negative time values in calendrical or astronomical calculations, modulo is ALWAYS what I need. The sign behavior of the remainder operator is simply a nuisance that has to be worked around. I haven't done much Python coding myself, but damn, I wish `%` worked as it does in Python in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the `%` operator returns the same sign as the divisor.  In C#, it returns the same sign as the dividend.  (Also see [Modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator))

In Python, `math.fmod` would give similar results to C#.

If you want to obtain `11` in C#, you probably need to say:

```
(((-1 % 12) + 12) % 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained why you are getting different results in the two languages, but it's important to realize that *both answers are correct* in the sense that, when you reverse the operations, you get back the original number.

In C#, the result of the integer division `-1 / 12` is `0`. `0 * 12` is `0`. To get back to the original `-1`, you need to add `-1`, which is what you got for the remainder operation.

In Python, `-1 / 12` is `-1`. `-1 * 12` is `-12`. To get back to the original `-1`, you need to add `11`. Which, again, is what you got for modulus.

So it's not merely a difference in what operation `%` performs, there's *also* a difference in how integer division is performed when the signs of the operands differ between the two languages. The behavior of `%` is chosen so that the quotient, multiplied by the divisor, and added to the remainder, results in the dividend. Changing how the quotient is calculated necessarily changes how the remainder is calculated.