# Calculation of degrees is inaccurate

Tags: c#, degrees, radians

I'm using the following code to convert radians to degrees and do some arithmetic on the same.

```
private double getDegrees(double rad)
{
    double deg = rad * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

     double degree = (-135 - deg) % 360;

     return degree;
}
```

The value calculates is inaccurate. I'm using the same code in Python and the result is quite accurate as follows,

```
def getDegree(rad):
    return (-135 - math.degrees(rad)) % 360
```

How do I get the accurate degrees with c#?

```
Input: -2.54 Output: 10.750966993188058
Input 2.57   Output 77.6960764459401
Input -0.62  Output 260.9199271359733
Input 0.52   Output 195.1409838350769
```

Note: The output is after `(-135 - deg) % 360;`

The output from c# is as follows,

```
Input -2.54  Output 11.0295281217168
Input 2.56   Output -282.127098553015
Input -0.63  Output -98.8646242270579
Input 0.51   Output -164.592296943409
```

Comment: Please define `inaccurate` for this case. Floating point math is almost never *100%* accurate.

Comment: From the fact you've got a negative number in your example and that you're comparing C# and Python, there's a chance you're getting negative numbers out. Try adding 360 to your result if it's negavtive.

Comment: I have included the input and the output

Comment: Yes - input, actual output and *expected* output is important. At the moment we don't know whether you're getting *radically* different results, or whether this is a precision issue.

Comment: % behaves differently across languages for negative numbers

Comment: i have included the result in c# @John

Comment: @bolov wow! that seems interesting

Comment: What has been said before the `%` operator is different between python and c#, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18106156/10608418 for a related question and a link to explanation.

Comment: @knoop @bolov that was the issue..... thank you so much to both and everyone who tried to help me out.. I have wasted 1 full day trying to figure out what went wrong. `((degree) % 360) + 360) % 360;` fixed the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean _radiantly_ different results? :)

Comment: @user1241241 Note that if your radian value is significantly positive (e.g. `8`), the solution mentioned in your comment may still return a negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `%` operator will return negative values in C# when the input is negative, you'll have to convert them back to positive by adding 360:

```
private double getDegrees(double rad)
{
     double deg = rad * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

     double degree = (-135 - deg) % 360;

     return degree < 0 ? degree + 360 : degree;
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LKT31980)